# How to separate a list item in to separate variables

Tags: list, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm working on a project for web scraping.

I run into an issue where I run a for loop to iterate through a list but it brings it back as one.

My aim is to separate each item inside the list and save it as a variable displaying it in a data frame, however, I'm faced with a block of text instead.

How would I go about doing this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

page_link = ("https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?sort=price-asc&"
             "radius=1500&postcode=lu15jf&onesearchad=Used&"
             "onesearchad=Nearly%20New&onesearchad=New&make=AUDI&model=A5"
             "&price-to=8500&year-from=2008&maximum-mileage=90000"
             "&transmission=Automatic&exclude-writeoff-categories=on")

request = requests.get(page_link)
conn = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(conn, "html.parser")

cars = soup.find_all("h2", {"class":"listing-title title-wrap"})
cars_specs = soup.find_all('ul', {"class" :'listing-key-specs '})

carlist = []
for car, specs in zip(cars, cars_specs):
    dic = {}
    dic["Car Model"]=car.find("a", {"class": "js-click-handler listing-fpa-link"}).text
    dic["Specs"] = specs.text
    carlist.append(dic)

df = pandas.DataFrame(carlist)
df
```

[image]

Comment: What does your dataframe `df` look like?

Comment: can you please post your expected output?

Comment: I've added a picture of the data frame, My desired output is that each spec be printed in individual columns

Comment: I hope my answer helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what would do the job is

```
df1 = df.Specs.str.split(pat='\n', expand=True)
df1 = df1.replace('',np.nan)

df1 = df1.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
df1.columns = ['Spec_' + str(x)  for x in list(df1)]

df1
          Spec_1 Spec_2        Spec_3 Spec_4  Spec_5     Spec_6  Spec_7
0  2008 (08 reg)  Coupe  77,500 miles   2.7L  187bhp  Automatic  Diesel
1  2008 (58 reg)  Coupe  69,170 miles   2.7L  187bhp  Automatic  Diesel
2  2008 (58 reg)  Coupe  84,700 miles   2.7L  187bhp  Automatic  Diesel
3  2008 (58 reg)  Coupe  53,800 miles   2.7L  187bhp  Automatic  Diesel
4  2009 (09 reg)  Coupe  85,000 miles   2.7L  187bhp  Automatic  Diesel
5  2008 (08 reg)  Coupe  74,000 miles   3.2L  261bhp  Automatic  Petrol
6  2008 (08 reg)  Coupe  67,000 miles   3.2L  261bhp  Automatic  Petrol
7           2008  Coupe  90,000 miles   2.7L  187bhp  Automatic  Diesel
8  2008 (58 reg)  Coupe  59,277 miles   2.7L  187bhp  Automatic  Diesel
9  2009 (09 reg)  Coupe  78,412 miles   2.7L  187bhp  Automatic  Diesel
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this is exactly what I needed. You also need to add import numpy as np for this to work.